How recognizes touch screen gestures in Avalonia ReactiveUI
I'm trying to approach Avalonia with the MVVM pattern. I'm attempting to create an application that recognizes touch screen gestures.
So far i've created applications with simple graphics, but I would like to be able to recognize gestures I make on the touchscreen. I'm trying to make my code recognize gestures to open and close the <border> inside the <SplitView.Pane>, but I don't know how to correctly call void TestGesture(...).
Here is part of my code cleaned from unnecessary features.


This is my MainWindowView avalonia:

<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:DomandaStack.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="DomandaStack.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="DomandaStack">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <SplitView IsPaneOpen="{Binding Path=IsOpen}"
                   OpenPaneLength="300"
                   CompactPaneLength="85"
                   DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"
                   PaneBackground="Transparent"
                   Background="white"
                   PanePlacement="Left">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Border Background="Yellow"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        PointerMoved="TestGesture">
                    <StackPanel Spacing="5">
                        <Button Content="Open"
                                Command="{Binding Path=OpenClosePanel_Command}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="8 10 0 0"
                                Width="65" Height="40"/>
                        
                        <ListBox Background="Transparent">
                            <ListBoxItem Content="Page 1"
                                         Height="50"
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            
                            <ListBoxItem Content="page 2"
                                         Height="50"
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            
                            <ListBoxItem Content="page 3"
                                         Height="50"
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            
                            <ListBoxItem Content="page 4"
                                         Height="50"
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <TransitioningContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentPage}"/>
                    
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Window>



And this in my MainWindowViewModel c#:

using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Controls.Selection;
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DomandaStack.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool _IsOpen = false;
        public bool IsOpen
        {
            get => _IsOpen;
            private set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _IsOpen, value);
        }


        public ICommand OpenClosePanel_Command { get; }
        private void OpenClosePanel()
        {
            IsOpen = !IsOpen;
        }


        private ViewModelBase _CurrentPage = new Page1ViewModel();
        public ViewModelBase CurrentPage
        {
            get => _CurrentPage;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _CurrentPage, value);
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            OpenClosePanel_Command = ReactiveCommand.Create(OpenClosePanel);
        }


        //How to bind a function like this?
        public void TestGesture(object sender, Avalonia.Input.PointerEventArgs e)
        {

            var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(sender as Control);

            //if(pointerMoving == LeftToRight)
            //{
            //  IsOpen = true;
            //}
            //if(pointerMoving == LeftToRight)
            //{
            //  IsOpen = false;
            //}
        }

    }
}


I would like to do something similar to this image


I'm probably approaching it wrong and maybe even using the wrong properties,
I hope you can understand;
Thank you for the help :)

Maybe this could be a starting point: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/reference/gestures/pullgesturerecognizer

I do not have much knowledge in implementing desktop applications for a device using a touchscreen. When it comes to using gestures like 2 fingers for zooming in and out as you can in websites on a smartphone MAY NOT exist as you don't exactly have 2 pointers, and I do not know of any libraries that handles this. Though it is still possible to implement some gestures (comparing it to a mouse and keyboard):

left click is equivalent of a single tap or short press on touchscreen

double click is equivalent of a 2 taps or short presses on touchscreen

Right click --> long press on backround of the application.

left click and drag --> mark/highlight words or similar.


